# How to Remove a CIFilter

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-image

I know when using a `CIFilter`, if you're using a `CIFilter` like `CISepiaTone`, you can essentially "remove" it by resetting it's value back to its initial value. However, for a `CIFilter` like `CIMinimumComponent`, which doesn't have a value component, how would you go about removing this filter? (assuming I have other chained filters that I want to remain)

Comment: I am having a somewhat similar problem. I don't understand how to "remove" a filter like 'CISepiaTone' by "resetting it's value back to its initial value." What would the code to do that look like? I really need help here thanks so much!